# How to make an Azure Function that was migrated from Javascript to Typescript build?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have a function that was initially created and deployed in Javascript.
I migrated it locally to Typescript and I can run it fine.
However, when it gets deployed via the Github integration (Build provider: App Service Build Service), it does not build the project. I've checked with Kudu, if I go to wwwroot, the `dist` folder is missing.

Here's my package json:

```json
{
  "name": "backup-function",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --project tsconfig.build.json",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "func start --verbose",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "engine": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.1.0",
    "durable-functions": "^2.1.0",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^3.5.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/node": "16.x",
    "azure-functions-core-tools": "^4.0.4915",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
    ...
  }
}
```

My host.json

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "hubName": "backup"
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to modify the file `C:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd` with Kudu:

On line 121, I added these 2 lines:

```
call npm install --production :: below this line
call npm install -D typescript
call npm run build
```

**Edit:**

The deployment with Azure App Service was very slow and sometimes timing out so I also manage to set this up with a github action:

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js project

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  NODE_VERSION: '18.x' # set this to the node version to use (supports 8.x, 10.x, 12.x)

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Node ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }} Environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3

      - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Npm'
        shell: bash
        run: |
          pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
          npm prune --production
          popd

      - name: 'Deploy'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: some-id
        with:
          app-name: 'your-function-name'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if below findings helps to fix the issue:

- Actually, when you use this command `npm run build` in the `package.json` file, it should create `dist` folder and run the function successfully as solved in this similar issue #[4803](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4803) from GitHub Repo - Azure Functions TypeScript Host issues.
- I am suspecting your **build** command in `package.json` could be causing an issue here. AFAIK, **build** command should be `tsc --project tsconfig.json`
- Though the above-mentioned command `npm run build` fails to create the `dist` folder, check the steps given by @Olina04 given in this SO Answer #[71846463](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71846463) on regarding the same issue and GitHub Ticket #[858](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/858#issuecomment-479571021).

Comment: Actually I think the issue is coming from c:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd which is just running `npm install --production` and doesn't include a build step.